# Interaction of InputField with Row (but not Column, Grid or Panel)

Tags: interface, inputfield, interactive

In Mathematica 9, there's an interaction between `InputField` and `Row`. The following fragment (without or without `Module` and options):

```
  Module[{opts},
     opts = { FieldSize -> 10, FieldHintStyle -> {Black}, 
       Appearance -> Framed};
     Row[
      {InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Field 1", opts],
       InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Field 2", opts],
       InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Field 3", opts]}]
     ]
```

Will correctly output the row of input fields and correctly handle text entered in the first field chosen by the user (not necessarily "Field 1"), but tabbing to and entering text in next field is converted to input form.

Whereas, removing `Row`, as in:

```
{InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Field 1"],
 InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Field 2"],
 InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Field 3"]}
```

Results in correct operation (including tabbing across fields). Passing the above list to Panel, `Column` or `Grid` (make two sets lists) also works fine.

Known issue?

Comment: Still the same (bug?) problem in v 11.0.1

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need [`Deploy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Deploy.html) to keep the Row elements from being selectable.
Here in version 7 compatible format:

```
Module[{opts},
 opts = {FieldSize -> 10, Appearance -> Framed};
 Row[{
   InputField["", String, opts],
   InputField["", String, opts], 
   InputField["", String, opts]
 }] // Deploy
]
```

Comment: That works, but how ugly that it's necessary for Row and not Column or Grid? What's the reason?

Comment: @alan Well, Tab doesn't seem to move between the fields of a Column or Grid so you don't see this specific problem, but strictly speaking I think `Deploy` should be used with all three, as otherwise you can select and overwrite the fields.

Comment: I can tab between fields even if arranged with Column and Grid.

Comment: @alancalvitti I was suspecting that `Grid` will work while `Column` will show the same behavior as `Row` but now it's strange...

Comment: @Kuba `Grid` and `Column` are both `GridBox` so should behave same. `Row` is `RowBox`. Would have though tab should work on all though. Since it does work in earlier versions it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: The `Row` option `Selectable -> False` also seems to work.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, that works too.  Any reason to prefer it over `Deploy`?

Comment: I don't have a reason to prefer either, except `Deploy` is less typing.  Oddly, `Selectable -> True` with `Column`/`Grid` does not make it operate like the default `Row`.  I suspect @MikeHoneychurch is right, or there's a deeper reason for `Row` to behave differently.