# Entering scientific notation in an InputField

Tags: dynamic, inputfield, gui-construction

I am trying to make an InputField for numeric input, but

```
InputField[Dynamic[num],Number]
```

Does not allow the user to type `1.3*^-13` or `1.3*10^-13`, for example.  The characters are simply disallowed in the field.  I tried

```
InputField[Dynamic[num],Expression]
```

which allows `1.3*10^-13` but does not allow the `1.3*^-13` shorthand.  The `*^` simply disappears when I type the `-`.  Further exploration shows that it the shorthand entry does work with positive exponents like `1.3*^6`.

So, my workaround is to use `Expression` and to remember to use explicit scientific notation whenever I have a negative exponent, but allowing an `Expression` in an `InputField` is always a dangerous proposition.  Is there any way to get this to work with `Number`?

Comment: I know this is kind of a weak question since I have already found a workaround, but I wanted to get this behavior documented here as it seems buggy to me.

Comment: It has further consequences. In free CDFs you can only use `Number` type `InputField`. For this case I'd use two `InputFields`, one for base and second for exponent and something between like `"*10^"` so a user will know what to do.

Comment: how about input as String, then `Read[StringToStream[],Number]]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This accepts a plain number or "E" format or "*^" notation..

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"];
 SetAttributes[sciInput, HoldFirst];
 inst[numstring_] := InputField[numstring, String, FieldSize -> {20, 1}, 
                   FieldHint -> "enter a number"];
 sciInput[result_] := 
       DynamicModule[{sig, nn}, 
          DynamicWrapper[Panel[Row[{inst[Dynamic@sig]}]], 
             Quiet[If[ (nn = Read[StringToStream[sig], Number]) === $Failed  , , 
                   If[NumberQ[nn], result = nn ]]], TrackedSymbols :> {sig}]];
 sciInput[number] // Deploy
 Dynamic[number]
```

Comment: Thanks to everybody for their help.  I am not quite ready to attack creating my own control type, so I will study these approaches carefully.  I selected this answer because it gives the option of entering the number in normal notation as well as scientific.

Answer (score 4):

This Answer is based upon Kuba's comment above regarding two `InputField`s, so credit should go to him for the idea, this is just an implementation. However, the problem interested me because I have a similar issue to solve regarding entering units into answers, and this question and Kuba's comment made me think of a related solution to that.

One can use `Interpretation` to make a relatively clean looking input that will "guide" the user through the input.

```
    numbIF[num_] := InputField[Dynamic[num], Number, FieldSize -> Full];
    expIF[exp_] := InputField[Dynamic[exp], Number, FieldSize -> Full];

    SetAttributes[sciInput, HoldFirst];
    sciInput[result_] := (Panel[
       Interpretation[{significand, exponent}, 
        Row[{numbIF[significand], Style[" x", 12], Superscript[10, expIF[exponent]]}], 
        result = significand*10^exponent]])

    sciInput[number]//Deploy
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The ideas for setting up the `Interpretation` came from the [Wolfram GeneralizedInput Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html).  Kuba pointed out including `//Deploy` to allowing tabbing between fields.

Kuba provided this nice alternative to the `Interpretation` approach. (Thanks)

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"]; SetAttributes[sciInput, HoldFirst]; 
    IF[num_] := InputField[num, Number, FieldSize -> Full]; 
    sciInput[result_] := DynamicModule[{sig, exp}, 
      DynamicWrapper[
       Panel[Row[{IF[Dynamic@sig], Superscript[10, IF[Dynamic@exp]]}, Style[" x", 12]]], 
       If[And @@ (NumericQ /@ {sig, exp}), result = sig 10^exp], 
       TrackedSymbols :> {sig, exp}]] ;

    sciInput[number] // Deploy 
    Dynamic[number]
```

Comment: @Kuba. Your comment led me to this answer. Please let me know if you feel like I stepped on your toes (really don't want to do that as newbie on the site). I couldn't figure out how to be able to tab from `InputField` to `InputField` which would really make the solution much nicer. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm glad you've made this answer :) `Deploy` will help you with [Tab issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31007/5478).

Comment: @Kuba I like your addition.  I don't think you need the `NumericQ` checking since you have defined the `InputField` to be `Number`.  In your example I still don't get the tab to advance between fields, but I will go back and look at the link you provided for additional clues. I haven't worked with `Deploy` before, so I will need to do some learning.

Comment: Tab is working for me. Notice that the code in comment is composed of couple separated lines. Try to run it without `If` too.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, the tabbing worked just fine when I added to my `Interpretation` code. Thanks again for your support as I get my feet wet with Mathematica.SE.