# Changing threshold for scientific notation from 10^6 so that InputField display is uniform

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, output, inputfield, number-representation

Related to but different from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44386/entering-scientific-notation-in-an-inputfield).

I'd like my [`InputField`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField.html) to display scientific notation not only for numbers larger than one million, but also for smaller numbers. Mathematica (version 10.3 on 64-bit Linux Mint) shows any number larger than 10^6 in scientific notation (whether in an `InputField` or outside). I want to set this threshold to be lower, at least across all `InputField` controls in a given module.

What I've tried is to use `ScientificForm` inside an `InputField`, but this causes it to look funny.

```
DynamicModule[{x},
 Grid[{
   {Manipulator[Dynamic[x], {10^5, 2*10^6}]},
   {InputField[Dynamic[ScientificForm[x, 2]]]},
   {InputField[Dynamic[x, 2]]}
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Output of code above]

When sliding beyond 10^6, it looks like:

[image: Output after sliding beyond 10^6]

I would like to have the same precision as the top `InputField` across all number ranges, while keeping the formatting as the second `InputField`, without the quotes. I thought I might be able to use [`$PrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html) but I wasn't sure how. I'd appreciate any help getting this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can simply set the `ShowStringCharacters->False` option in the `Style` of the `InputField`:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, 
 Grid[{
  {Manipulator[Dynamic[x], {10^5, 2*10^6}]},
  {InputField[Dynamic[Style[ScientificForm[x, 2], ShowStringCharacters -> False]]]},
  {InputField[Dynamic[x, 2]]}
  }]
 ]
```

[image]

compare also this answer:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6294/45128

Answer (score 1):

I've succeeded in doing this to my satisfaction. It's rather crude, and uses [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) to keep the number in exponent form. There may be a more elegant way to do this (comments appreciated), but this works for simple cases.

```
ScientificFormNumber[x_, precision_] := Block[{mantissa, exponent},
   {mantissa, exponent} = MantissaExponent[x];
   N[Round[(mantissa*10*10^(precision-1))]/10^(precision-1)]*
    Defer[10]^(exponent - 1)
 ];

DynamicModule[{x},
 Grid[{
   {Manipulator[Dynamic[x], {10^5, 2*10^6}]},
   {InputField[Dynamic[ScientificForm[x, 2]]]},
   {InputField[Dynamic[ScientificFormNumber[x, 2]]]},
   {InputField[Dynamic[x, 2]]}
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Output of above code]